# Can you embed a 960 grid system within a div?

Tags: html, css, grid, 960.gs

Is it possible to put a whole 960 grid inside a div on the page?

I need to make a page wider than 960px, so I thought I might have the sidebars laid out outside the 960 grid, and have the 960 grid control the middle column.

Comment: Why not just use a wider grid system? 1280px is another standard width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you just need to assign the parent div as the container_12. 
Then you can use the child elements the grid_# that works for you.

But it would be better if you updated the 960.css with the new resolution values. I.E. 1024.css